# Windows version of wcswidth_l

Tags: c++, windows, text, console

I have some text to write to the Windows console that I need to know the real width of in columns. wcswidth_l seems to be the best option on platforms that have it (though `mbswidth_l()` would be better since I have no desire to use wchar_t, but for some reason it doesn't exist). But in addition to other platforms, I need something that works on Windows. Although it's unlikely that there's a portable solution, I don't know of any solution at all on Windows. I think the console has an API for getting cursor position and such, so I could write the text out and check the change in position. That would be accurate I guess, but writing out extra output isn't acceptable at all.

How does one go about getting the column width of a string or character on Windows?

Edit:

wcswidth_l returns the number of console columns used to display a string. Some characters take up one column and others, e.g. japanese characters, take up two.

As an example the 'column width' of "a あ" is four. 'a' is one, ' ' is one, and 'あ' is two. (Assuming the console is set up to actually display non-ascii characters that is). Also it'd be nice if the API supports strings using codepage 65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: What's the reason for no extra output? Performance or keeping track of it?

Comment: UTF-8 cannot be set as the current codepage. I am afraid you should get used to using UTF-16 (wchar). Yes it is a shame, but UTF-8 wasn't published until 1993, when Windows NT was about to launch. But really nobody should ever write an ANSI or MBCS windows application ever, ever, ever again.

Comment: @chris performance mainly, although I haven't actually measured the cost of the extra output. We also keep a count of what's output, but I think writing directly with the console API would work around that.

Comment: @Ben The program isn't mainly a Windows program. There are some unfortunate limitations on the use of UTF-8 in Windows programs, but it can be used. For example you can set the console output cp to 65001 and writing UTF-8 to the console works. Personally I regard wchar_t as legacy from when people really thought that fixed size codepoints would help make text handling simpler (wchar_t is supposed to be fixed size, though UTF-16 isn't), but as you can see even on platforms that have fully embraced UTF-8 I've had to compromise because that legacy has resulted in no alternative to `wcswidth_l`.

Comment: I did not know you could set the console to work with UTF-8 -- thanks.

Comment: Well, good luck on that working with direct console API. If you haven't seen, I updated my answer with some steps that would write to the console without the user being able to tell a difference. Creating a buffer would just be needed once at the beginning; the only thing taking any extra time are `WriteConsole` calls (though I'm not sure how they play out performance-wise).

Comment: @chris thanks, I may give that a try to see what the performance is like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the Windows Console API is located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Secondly, is the function you're looking for [GetConsoleFontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

I'll try to quickly type an example in a second.

EDIT: Here you go. Forgive me if it there's a small error. I actually found it was even easier. `GetCurrentConsoleFont` fills in a `COORD` structure on the way to you getting the index to pass to `GetConsoleFontSize`, so step saved :)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 //XP, 0x0601=windows 7
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO cfi;
    GetCurrentConsoleFont (hStdOutput, FALSE, &cfi);

    //cfi.dwFontSize.X == x size
    //cfi.dwFontSize.Y == y size
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't mind invisible output, you can use `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` to pretty much have an invisible console window at your command while leaving yours unaffected. `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` will tell you the cursor position, at which point you can use `WriteConsole` to write to your buffer (invisibly), and check the cursor location again versus the number of characters actually written. Note that checking the cursor location beforehand would not require clearing the screen to use this method.

If you cannot afford to do extra output, visible or invisible, I'm not sure there really is a possibility.

Comment: No, I don't think `GetConsoleFontSize` is what I'm looking for. This appears to return information about a font. I'm looking to find out how man _columns_ are used up by specific strings or characters when they are displayed in the console.

Comment: I did eventually decide to go with creating a console screen buffer. There are shortcomings like having to choose between either allowing inaccurate results or doing special handling for any anything wider than the console width or longer than the console buffer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Portable approach

Since width of characters depends more on characters themselves rather than the system on which they are displayed (ok, there might be excepetions, but they should be rather rare), one can use separate function to do that (on Windows too).  This requires Unicode characters as it makes it much easier to analyze width of strings, but one for sure can write a wrapper to convert between encodings.

#### Available implementation

[Here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c) is suitable and portable implementation, which one can plug in into his application and fallback to use it on Windows.