# Width of wide character strings

Tags: c, wchar-t

I need a function to determine columns needed for a wide-character string in  different OS. In **glibc** there is a function `wcswidth`. It doesn't seem to be available in Windows.

Are there alternatives to it in Windows that I can use? Or maybe there are already available some cross-platfrom standard funcions to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Github repo that claims to offer a platform independent library to resolve this: https://github.com/joshuarubin/wcwidth9

Archived link: http://archive.is/C5UAF

Comment: You might want to post the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900399/windows-version-of-wcswidth-l as well.